# Python: Parsing JSON String List for Each JSON Object

Tags: python, string, json, list

I use the [json module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) and the dumps method to obtain a string which represents a list of json objects :

```
import json
jsonstring = json.dumps(data)
```

I would like to iterate over this string to obtain each JSON object as a string.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.  I have tried the following:

```
for jsonobject in jsonstring:
    print jsonobject
```

But what happens is that each single letter is printed separately rather than the jsonobject as a whole.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? json.dumps() will return a single string representation of 'data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over your data before you turn it into a string, then turn each element of the data into JSON:

```
for d in data:
    jsonstring = json.dumps(d)
```

Comment: thanks ned!  that does exactly what i need and didn't realize it.  sorry about the noobiness...

Answer (score 3):

```
for jsonobject in json.loads(jasonstring):
    print jsonobject
```

Comment: thanks john.  this does it... and jsonobject is a unicoded string.